# Android TextView not properly displaying Arabic Text with custom font

Tags: android, fonts, textview, arabic

I'm developing an Android app that uses Arabic text. The text in TextView is being displayed using a custom font. The issue is that some of the pause marks are not displaying correctly. The same text, in the same font, displays flawlessly on the browser when I use HTML. But there are problems with Android TextView.

**Browser display:**

[image]

**TextView display:**
[image]

I've tried multiple solution including followings, but none works

- Tried increasing letter spacing
- Used same html code in textView with the help of Html.fromHtml method
- defined font Family through xml as well as through Java typeface
- Tried enabling/disabling Ligatures using fontFeatureSettings

I'm applying following style on textView

```
 <style name="ArabicTextViewStyle">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/alquran_indopak_by_quranwbw_v_4_2_2</item>
    <item name="singleLine">false</item>
    <item name="android:textDirection">rtl</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30dp</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceTitleMedium" />
</style>
```

HTML file is given below:

```
<html>
   <head>
    <style>
      @font-face { font-family: JuneBug; src: url('AlQuran-IndoPak-by-QuranWBW.v.4.2.2.ttf'); } 
      h2, p {
         font-family: JuneBug;
      }
    </style>
   </head>
   <body>
    <h2>
        صِرَاطَ الَّذِیْنَ اَنْعَمْتَ عَلَیْهِمْ ۙ۬— غَیْرِ الْمَغْضُوْبِ عَلَیْهِمْ وَلَا الضَّآلِّیْنَ 
    </h2>
   </body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure why the same text and font appear correctly in the browser but not on Android. The text at both places is in UTF-8 encoding.
I've tried on the Android Studio emulator as well as on multiple physical devices, but the issue remains the same.

Comment: Likely a bug in the Android framework. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583188/android-textview-vs-webview-font-rendering

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer here [Arabic pronounce symbol not showing correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65991110/arabic-pronounce-symbol-not-showing-correctly)
All Arabic characters can be encoded using a single UTF-16 code unit (2 bytes), but they may take either 2 or 3 UTF-8 code units (1 byte each), so if you were just encoding Arabic, UTF-16 would be a more space efficient option.
Check if this works and also try https://github.com/mobin-tabaran-intelligent-structure/MTTextView for your font.

Comment: Still has the same issue with UTF-16 encoding. It's not an encoding issue because the exact text and font work fine in Html with UTF-8 encoding.